# How to integrate NewRelic App Monitoring tool with Cloudify?

Tags: server, monitoring, newrelic, health-monitoring, cloudify

I am looking to forward integrate NewRelic Agent with Existing Cloudify 2.7 Environment. 
Since Cloudify apps are running in individual paths and each deployment takes to apps running on different paths, it's not possible to assign the app server to newrelic. How can I over come this?

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you are trying to accomplish.

You recipe can install the NewRelic agent and configure it to connect to NewRelic.

Alternatively, if the NewRelic agent has an API or CLI, you can add a

```
monitors{
}
```

section to your recipe. This section will collect the required stats from the local agent and publish them to the Cloudify Manager.

More information is available here: http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/plugins_and_probes/probes.html

The collected monitors are then available using the Manager REST API. You can then use a separate process to poll the metrics from the manager API and send them to NewRelic. Look at: http://getcloudify.org/guide/2.7/restapi/restdoclet.html

and the API at

```
/{version}/deployments/{appName}/service/{serviceName}/instances/{instanceId}/metrics
```